# How do I make a synchronous request in RestKit?

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

How do I make a synchronous request using [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit)?

I used earlier this way(SBJSON):

```
UIDevice *myDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];

    NSString *deviceUDID = [myDevice uniqueIdentifier];

    double v = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]doubleValue]; 
    NSString *version=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %.1f",deviceType,v];
    NSString *encodedParam1 =[version stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"method=views.get&view_name=client_list",nil];

    NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [requestString UTF8String] length: [requestString length]];

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/index.php?oper=StoreDeviceId&device_id=%@&device_version=%@",deviceUDID,encodedParam1];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];

    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [request setHTTPBody: requestData];

    //Data returned by WebService

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil ];

    [request release];

    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSDictionary *dict1 = [returnString JSONValue];
```

same operation how to handle using restkit framework.

Advance thanks

Comment: mmm if you do that your app will freeze while the server process the request, are you sure you want to do that? you can use blocks with Restkit so you write your code as "synchronous" but you get it asynchronous

Comment: Did my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a synchronous post using RKClient

```
//Configure RKLog
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);

//Set Client
RKClient *client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURLString:@"some_base_url"];

//Params to be send
NSDictionary *queryParameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"first_value",@"2",@"second_value",nil];

//Prepare the request and send it
RKRequest *request = [client post:@"path" params:queryParameters delegate:nil];
RKResponse *response = [request sendSynchronously];

//Process the response
NSString *stringResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[response body] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dict1 = [stringResponse JSONValue];
```

but I recommend to use asynchronous calls using blocks instead!.

Answer (score 0):

To make a synchronous request using RestKit, use `RKRequest`'s `-sendSynchronously` method after setting up the the `RKRequest` instance as normal.

Comment: can you give sample code for that request and respond operation